# Xamarin solution: exception when I try to use a component in the same project (different namespace)

Tags: xamarin.forms, custom-controls

In my Xamarin solution, I added a new library project in a `Controls` solution folder. From my `XAML` in `Views` I called my component and everything was working fine.

I don't know if something changed today after the update to `iOS 10` and `Visual Studio for Mac` but not if I try to compile my solution, I receive an error

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. --->
>   Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 43:38. Type Doughnut
>   not found in xmlns
>   clr-namespace:Mobile.Controls.Wheel;assembly=Mobile.Controls.Wheel
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Internals.XamlTypeResolver.Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlTypeResolver.Resolve
>   (System.String qualifiedTypeName, System.IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider)

The `XAML` page is so defined:

```
<ContentPage [...]
    xmlns:ctl="clr-namespace:Mobile.Controls.Wheel;assembly=Mobile.Controls.Wheel" 
    x:Class="Views.DashboardPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <ctl:Doughnut HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

`Doughnut` is a class derived from `ContentView` in `Mobile.Controls.Wheel`.

Comment: This namespace `Mobile.Controls.Wheel` is at the same assembly of your content page? If yes, try remove the assembly specification at the xmlns declaration to be like : `xmlns:ctl="clr-namespace:Mobile.Controls.Wheel"`.

Comment: No, my content page as a different assembly. Basically, I want to create a control in SkiaSharp for a chart (a Doughnut here) and reuse it everywhere. It is a component.

Comment: All right then. And the dll package generated for this control is named `Mobile.Controls.Wheel.dll`? Did you checked if the assembly name declared on the properties of your library is this one?

Comment: Thanks @DiegoRafaelSouza yes, the dll generated is `Mobile.Controls.Wheel.ddl`. I checked inside the solution fine and the namespace is the same. I deleted all `obj` and `bin` folders and rebuild: error is still there

Comment: can you share sample project?

Comment: @Enrico, the problem that you are facing occurs only when you have your custom control in a separate PCL?

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue with iOS earlier,

> Adding empty class in PCL wth empty static **init()** method and calling
>   it on **iOS’s AppDelegate** method solves this Issue when either “Dont’t
>   Link” or “Link SDK assemblies only” is selected in “Linker Options” of iOS Build options.

In your **Doughnut** class, add a Empty **Do-Nothing static Init** Method and call this method from iOS's AppDelegate:

> In Doughnut.cs add the below method

```
//Do Nothing Init Method:
public static void Init(){

}
```

> In AppDelegate.cs, add the below line before calling ***LoadApplication*** method

```
Mobile.Controls.Wheel.Doughnut.Init();
```

Hope this solves your issue, if any information needed let me know.